# how to create database schema with hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, schema

using

```
   < property name="hbm2ddl.auto"> create< / property >
```

only creates the tables, and whenever a schema does not exist, hibernate fails to create the table because the schema does not exist.

Comment: Its true. I solved this issue using maven to create the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate will not create the schema for you, but maybe you can tell your DBMS to run some script before hibernate starts to create the schema objects. I found something [here](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/01/hibernate-hbm2ddl-wont-create-schema.html) and I think you can use it as a start point.