# Hibernate database creation

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to create database schema on application server startup.
I use hebernate 4.1.9 with annotations and hibernate.cfg.xml for configuration.

So the problem is that I cann't fully understand what I should do to create schema and after that use it in application. Of course I want to perform schema creation only on first start and on the next start I want to update it.

I'm trying to use hbn2ddl.auto in update state, but database doesn't creates. May be I should use somethin like `INIT=create schema IF NOT EXISTS myschema` in the end of the hibernate.connection.url??

Also I have an exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

But in hibernate.cfg.xml there is such string:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

Can anybody describe it to me?

Comment: Try looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373944/how-to-create-database-schema-with-hibernate-cfg-xml) and the link within its answer.

Comment: I saw the link in the answer before, but it doesn't help because I don't want to right additional creation script and adding INIT block to the url won't create the schema. Actually I'm trying to understand why?

Comment: The Hibernate documentation defines **hibernate.connection.url** merely as the JDCB URL. The [MySQL Connector/J reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) doesn't define an **INIT** property.

I believe the point of the linked article to be you have to bite the bullet and at least create an empty schema yourself.

Comment: I solve the problem. Connector/J documentation doesn't define an INIT property, yes it's truth. But it defines createDatabase property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem by myself. I should add createDatabase=true to hibernate.connection.url

Comment: Spiffy. `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` is another choice.

Comment: When I said about INIT property I mean that I was trying to find something like it. So I found it on your link. Thank you.